# Can I copy line above my find line in output?

Tags: c#, find, line

I have a little problem with duplicates lines above my found line.
 `if (value1.StartsWith("***") & value1.EndsWith("useky"))` with this code I find line but I would like to view line above this . Is there some code for it? I'd like console to write a line above`Console.WriteLine(lineabovefind);`  and I will copy wanted line. Thank you for every piece of advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires you to enumerate your collection use plain old index advance method:

```
var lines = new string[]{"whatever", "else", "***useky"};

for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    var thisLine = lines[i];
    if (i > 0 && thisLine.StartsWith("***") && thisLine.EndsWith("useky")) {
        Console.WriteLine(lines[i-1]);
    }
}
```

The code above will print 'else'.